# I have downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.1, copied it to a DVD and tried to boot it from it. It requires a user and password which I do not possess

Tags: login, livedvd

I have tried (user/password)=(blank/blank) and (ubuntu/blank). The latter produces a loop... 
I read an older post that said to add a user but it doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download and burn again. It was not a complete image.

If you used torrent to download the image, just start it up again and make sure it starts to seed. It probably only downloaded 99.9% of it.

If you used browser install, either switch to torrent, or download through browser again.

On the download page it should give you the hash of the file. You can check the ISO to make sure hash matches, if does, you have the whole image

**Edit**

On Windows you can download and use a free tool called hashcalc to check the sum

[This is a list of hashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)

Check the version you downloaded and the hash of your iso should match to that of site. If it don't match, it's not a complete image.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

If the default username and password are not working then it is true the install could be in incomplete and I do agree that a live USB is quite handy, however, it is possible to add or alter users from the command line. If you verify the validity of the installation you can add a user via command line like this:

- Ctrl + Alt + F2 You should see a command line.
- `sudo adduser [your new username]` There will be a few prompts to follow
- Ctrl + Alt + F7 Should put you back at the regular gui login.

**Original**

Generally when this is the case the defaults are "ubuntu" and a blank password. There are other ways in but hopefully we wont need those.

Comment: OP- This may work, but only attempt this solution if hash matches up. If it don't match, it may work, but you could be opening yourself up to headaches in the future.

Comment: Agreed. If the install is not valid just take it from the top.